Is it possible to execute a plaintext attack on a slidefair cipher
there.
Ive got the cipher text: GKFJMNMJLRHLJKSMPFLMYCS 
And an answer: EEADIHHHJFEFHENGLZGKWQP
The person that encrypted this had done it on a slidefair cipher with an unknown key that i currently need. Thank you.

This question is similar to: How to find the keyword of the Playfair cipher, given the plaintext and the ciphertext?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
